# Unable to keep the changes in the textformfield when multiple textformfield is created dynamically while audio is playing

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm creating an application that will have multiple textformfields and multiple controllers that are created dynamically. Also, I'm adding an audio player. The application is used to hear audio and type the text. But when I create texteditingcontroller dynamically. When I pause or play the audio audio the text will be loaded like how it was when the screen was created. code is added below.

```
import 'package:audio_session/audio_session.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:just_audio/just_audio.dart';
import 'package:rxdart/rxdart.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List<String> data1 = [
    "It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining ",
    "essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum ",
    "passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.",
    "It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining ",
    "essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum ",
    "passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.",
  ];
  bool _isPlaying = false;

  final player = AudioPlayer(); // Create a player

  Duration? duration;

  @override
  void initState() {
    loadAudio();
    super.initState();
  }

  int? hours = 0;
  int? minutes = 0;
  int? seconds = 0;

  void loadAudio() async {
    try {
      // AAC example: https://dl.espressif.com/dl/audio/ff-16b-2c-44100hz.aac
      duration = await player.setAudioSource(
        AudioSource.uri(
          Uri.parse("https://dl.espressif.com/dl/audio/ff-16b-2c-44100hz.mp3"),
        ),
      );
      hours = duration!.inHours;
      minutes = (duration!.inMinutes % 60);
      seconds = (duration!.inSeconds % 60);
      setState(() {});
    } catch (e) {
      print("Error loading audio source: $e");
    }
  }

  _playAudio() async {
    if (_isPlaying) {
      player.pause();
      setState(() {
        _isPlaying = !_isPlaying;
      });
    } else {
      player.play();
      setState(() {
        _isPlaying = !_isPlaying;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Audio Player'),
      ),
      body: ListView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
        children: [
          ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount: data1.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              final TextEditingController controller = TextEditingController();
              controller.text = data1[index];
              return TextFormField(
                controller: controller,
                maxLines: null,
              );
            },
          ),
          Center(
            child: IconButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  _playAudio();
                },
                icon: _isPlaying
                    ? const Icon(Icons.pause)
                    : const Icon(Icons.play_arrow)),
          ),
          Center(
            child: Text("Duration = $hours : $minutes : $seconds"),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be happening because you're initializing the TextEditingController inside the itemBuilder.
So it creates a new instance every time the widget is rebuilt.
To avoid this, you could try to initialize them outside the itemBuilder (initState or as a part of your state class ) so that they persist the state changes.